# __repr__ returned non-string type error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is a dummy example of my class method:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name

  def __repr__(self):
      for i in range(0,5):
          if i == 0:
             print(self.name)
          else:
             print("-")
          i += 1


m1 = A("x")
m1
```

It prints out the result for me. However, in the meantime, it gives an error saying that `__repr__` returned non-string. I understand that I need to use return instead of print for `__repr__`, however return would stop my program when the first condition is met. I also tried yield but had no luck.

I know this dummy program looks ridiculous and I could have used some other methods instead of `__repr__` to print out the results. But this is just a simplified version of my actual program and I have to use `__repr__` or `__str__` for some reasons.

Comment: Yes, that's right, your `__repr__` method doesn't return a string, it returns `None`. Why are you `print`ing in it? *"return would stop my program when the first condition is met"* - correct, you need to **build the whole string** then return it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two basic problems.  The first is that you altered the loop index within the loop -- bad form, but not at all fatal.  The second is that you fail to return a value.

**IMMEDIATE REPAIR**

```
def __repr__(self):
  for i in range(0,5):
      if i == 0:
         val = self.name
      else:
         val += "-"

  return val
```

However, even this is ineffective.

**EVEN BETTER**

It appears that you want the name with four dashes appended.  Why not just do that?

```
def __repr__(self):
    return self.name + "----"
```

Comment: "As a result,  i will take on even values only" Not exactly. As variable i assignment is the last instruction in the loop, var i will be rewritten by the next iteration to the next value in range, and so the assignment to i does nothing.

Comment: Ah, right!  I incorrectly generalized from another use case.  I'll update the answer; thanks!

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you want your `__repr__` output exactly as you are printing it. For that you will just need to change the logic a bit. Something like this should work:

```
  def __repr__(self):
      string = ""
      for i in range(0,5):
          if i == 0:
             string += self.name
          else:
             string += "-"
          i += 1
      return string
```